# Is there a `with_self` or similar block for a Ruby enum?

Tags: ruby

Similar to how, in Ruby, you can do

```
[1, 2, 3].each.with_index { |num, index| }
```

I'd like to chain that to also add a reference to the top level array without having to assign said array to a different variable before the block, like so:

```
[1, 2, 3].each.with_index.with_self { |num, index, array| }
```

Does such a method exist, or any alternatives outside of the obvious of having a top-level variable set?

My specific case is off a Ruby script that I'd like to golf as much as readably possible.
I have an input file with rows, and I'm reading the file like so:

```
STDIN.each_line.with_index
```

But also need to back-reference the original "array", but because of `each_line` the array becomes an Enumerator. I could break it up and parse the pieces of course, but trying to keep the script concise. The `with_self` would be perfect, but it doesn't appear to exist.

Comment: _"any alternatives"_ – maybe, but for what? Why do you need the array reference within the block in the first place? What is the specific problem you’re trying to solve?

Comment: I don't think there even *is* an underlying array when you do `STDIN.each_line.with_index {...}`.  The block runs immediately after each line of input, so there could not exist an array that holds every line of input, because the array would have to hold input not yet provided to the program.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for [`Object#tap`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Object.html#method-i-tap):

```
[1, 2, 3].tap { |a| a.each_with_index { |num, index| ... }
```

---

To go from enumerator to Array:

```rb
STDIN.each_line.to_a
```

or just

```rb
STDIN.readlines
```

---

Last: Your idea of a `with_self` does not work if it goes after the `each_with_index`, because `self` would become another Enumerator rather than the Array that you are looking for.

Edit: Look at Cary's answer for how you can bent Ruby to your will. :-)

Comment: Was looking at `tap`, but because it's off an Enumerator, it wasn't playing nicely. I was trying to cut details to make this more broad and helpful for others, but I'll edit the original post to be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that as follows.

```
module Enumerable
  def with_self
    arr = to_a.map(&:first)
    loop { yield [*self.next, arr] }
  end
end
```

```
[1, 2, 3].each.with_index.with_self { |n,i,arr| puts [n,i,arr] }
  #=> [1, 0, [1, 2, 3]]
  #   [2, 1, [1, 2, 3]]
  #   [3, 2, [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: This is neat, and a very cool thing to see/know! However, becomes an issue for golf/conciseness.

Comment: True, but this is not [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). Your question is very specific: you asked if there is a method `with_self` that does what you want it to do. That is the question I have answered.